# litmus-rt scheduling traces

Tags: linux, scheduling, trace

I would like to gather scheduling information on my RT-tasks (deadline - finish). When I follow the tutorial on https://wiki.litmus-rt.org/litmus/Tracing, I receive the error: "could not open feathertrace device (/dev/litmus/sched_trace13): No such file or directory". I know the tutorial indicates that the default location of the sched_trace device may need to be altered, but I can't seem to find the correct location. I guess what I'm trying to do should be fairly easy, am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the Feather-Trace wasn't enabled by default when applying the litmus-rt patch to my kernel. After entering menuconfig (`make menuconfig`) I disabled the  RELOCATABLE dependency under processor type and features. Afterwards the option Feather-Trace Infrastructure was made visible, found under LITMUS RT -> tracing.

Comment: A warning has been added to the tracing tutorial page of the website now.